# C# - When to convert values of class properties

Tags: c#, class, get, set, public

I would like to know which is considered more correct or better practice:

Part of the class:

```
public class foo
{
private Single amount;
public Single Amount
{
get
    {
        return amount;
    }
set
    {
        amount = Convert.ToSingle(value);
    }
}
}
```

or

```
public Single Amount {get;set;}
```

and converting the value in the code such as this:

```
foo myFoo = new foo();
myFoo.Amount = Convert.ToSingle(somevalue);
```

I will be getting the values (somevalue) from a database so I could easily pass all the values in as strings to the class and handle all the conversion there (or do the conversion in the data access layer). I just want to know which is better practice (or something I didn't think of).

Comment: The second is more readable for me.

Comment: Your first example is constrained by `Single` anyway, since it's the property type. Unless `value` can be implicitly cast, it will never get in to your setter.

Comment: The first one wont work because you can only pass a single to the get of a single property. That makes the Convert.ToSingle do nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is definitely preferable IMO:

```
public Single Amount { get; set; }
```

You don't want your class doing obscure things in the background that are not clear from the outside (like type casting).

It's the job of the outside code to conform to the class property format, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the behavioral difference, The performance should be negligable

Comment: They are not the same, the behavior is different.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason they have specified the short version is such that you don't have to write the whole long version, so you should start out with the short version:

```
public Single Amount { get; set; }
```

Implicit conversion is a very bad idea, you'll certainly want explicit conversion such that your user knows that conversion is going on and your function doesn't accidentally take anything. Consider that when you do conversion inside your property your property would be expecting an object, that could be whatever object that's convertible to a Single and thus you introduce the possibility for errors.

You don't want the user of your property to discover that he assigned something wrong to it that caused it to become `0` for some reason, you rather want the compiler to warn him in advance than him having to go through some though debugging.

It's not your responsibility to convert whatever they give to you, but rather expect them to give a Single...